# Trying to parse xml file for javascript quiz

Tags: javascript, html, xml, parsing

I am trying to create a javascript quiz, that gets the questions from a xml file. At the moment I am only starting out trying to parse my xml file without any success. Can anyone point me to what I am doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="spmArr">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var quizXML = '<quiz><Sporsmal tekst="bla bla bla"/><alternativer><tekst>bla</tekst><tekst>bli</tekst><tekst correct="yes">ble</tekst></alternativer><Sporsmal tekst="More blah"/><alternativer><tekst>bla bla</tekst><tekst correct="yes">bli bli</tekst><tekst>ble ble</tekst></alternativer></quiz>'

var quizDOM = $.xmlDOM( quizXML );

quizDOM.find('quiz > Sporsmal').each(function() {

var sporsmalTekst = $(this).attr('tekst');
var qDiv = $("<div />")
.addClass("item")
.addClass("sporsmal")
.appendTo($(".spmArr"));
var sTekst = $("<h2/>")
.html(sporsmalTekst)
.appendTo(qDiv);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try this in my browser the classes and div are not being created. And the page is just blank. Am i doing something wrong when I intialize the xml?

edited to add prototype.js and close function

Comment: but you did load the library (jQuery or Prototype)?

Comment: Yes. I'm sory, forgot to write it into the code window above. I rewrote the wholde thing to make it easier to read, and forgot all about it. But it is added in my original file. In the header.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're forgetting to close your .each call. append `);` after the statement for sTekst and your call will parse correctly.